# Proguard in Android, Delete org.mozilla.javascript.tools

Tags: java, android, proguard

i'm configuring proguard in android file: 'proguard-project.txt'. I have some troubles and i read that i need to delete:

`org.mozilla.javascript.tools` package from the `js.jar` file. How i can delete this?

my errors are like:

```
[2013-08-31 13:05:27 -] Warning: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.ContextWindow: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JPanel
[2013-08-31 13:05:27 -] Warning: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.ContextWindow: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
[2013-08-31 13:05:27 -] Warning: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.ContextWindow$1: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ComponentListener
[2013-08-31 13:05:27 -] Warning: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.ContextWindow$1$1: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
[2013-08-31 13:05:27 -] Warning: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.ContextWindow$2: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ContainerListener
[2013-08-31 13:05:27 -] Warning: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.EvalTextArea: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JTextArea
```

before i tried to use `-dontwarn for this packages`, but when i used it eclipse display an error: **"out heap space"**

Or if you have if you have another solution, please share to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `-dontwarn java.awt.**,javax.swing.**` should be fine for this case.

The error "Out of heap space" in Eclipse is probably not related to these warnings. You should try giving Eclipse a larger heap in `eclipse.ini` in Eclipse's main directory, e.g. `-Xmx1024m`.

Comment: Thanks. My partner do something like that.